# Could not download gradle-4.0.0.jar No cached version available for offline mode

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle, offline-mode

I am getting this error -

"Could not download gradle-4.0.0.jar (com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0): No cached version available for offline mode" everytime I create a new project on Android Studio"

The following is the screenshot from android studio of how the project looks after creation -
[android studio screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONXh5.png)

build.gradle(Module:app) is also missing in every new project I create.

I've tried many things but I am unable to resolve this problem. What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to disable gradle offline mode. This is how you can do it in andorid studio 4.1

[Toggle gradle offline mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LzXpu.png)

Comment: the toggle is empty and shows nothing in gradle